# Do different MySQL connections live in different threads?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a webapp which is hosted on an apache server that runs php scripts that connect to a MySQL database.

I know that Apache creates threads and processes to run different scripts when it receives requests, but I'm having a problem when more than one user tries to run a script that calls a stored procedure: one core of the server starts to operate at 90% while the other is only at 0%, which makes the process particularly slow when more than one person is using it at once.

Is there a way to take advantage of the processors full potential?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each MySQL connection starts its own thread in the `mysqld` process. But one MySQL connection is fixed to one thread. MySQL has no support for utilizing multiple cores for an individual connection.

Mysqld also runs numerous other helper threads at all times. Connection manager thread, replication threads, deadlock detection threads, various InnoDB threads for reading and writing, etc.

For more details, read:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-threads.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-threads.html
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core

If your server has idle cores, then it's possible there isn't enough concurrent work to schedule threads over the multiple cores.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll look into that.